# How to put function arguments within loop

Tags: r, for-loop, macros

I have been struggling with putting arguments of a function within a loop.
What I am trying to do if following:

Get this:

```
testResult1.2<-ddply(payments_All_cum_pct,"Vintage",summarise,
                     N_obs = sum(!is.na(TotalDue)),
                     Sum_TotalDue    = sum(TotalDue, na.rm=TRUE), 
                     Mean_TotalDue = mean(TotalDue,na.rm = TRUE),
                     wm1 = weighted.mean(Month1,TotalDue,na.rm=TRUE),
                     wm2 = weighted.mean(Month2,TotalDue,na.rm=TRUE),
                     wm3 = weighted.mean(Month3,TotalDue,na.rm=TRUE),
                     wm4 = weighted.mean(Month4,TotalDue,na.rm=TRUE),
                     wm5 = weighted.mean(Month5,TotalDue,na.rm=TRUE),
                     wm6 = weighted.mean(Month6,TotalDue,na.rm=TRUE),
                     wm7 = weighted.mean(Month7,TotalDue,na.rm=TRUE),
                     wm8 = weighted.mean(Month8,TotalDue,na.rm=TRUE),
                     wm9 = weighted.mean(Month9,TotalDue,na.rm=TRUE),
                     wm10 = weighted.mean(Month10,TotalDue,na.rm=TRUE),
                     wm11 = weighted.mean(Month11,TotalDue,na.rm=TRUE),
                     wm12 = weighted.mean(Month12,TotalDue,na.rm=TRUE),
                     wm13 = weighted.mean(Month13,TotalDue,na.rm=TRUE),
                     wm14 = weighted.mean(Month14,TotalDue,na.rm=TRUE),
                     wm15 = weighted.mean(Month15,TotalDue,na.rm=TRUE),
                     wm16 = weighted.mean(Month16,TotalDue,na.rm=TRUE),
                     wm17 = weighted.mean(Month17,TotalDue,na.rm=TRUE),
                     wm18 = weighted.mean(Month18,TotalDue,na.rm=TRUE)
)
```

Into something like this:

```
testResult1.2<-ddply(payments_All_cum_pct,"Vintage",summarise,
                     N_obs = sum(!is.na(TotalDue)),
                     Sum_TotalDue    = sum(TotalDue, na.rm=TRUE), 
                     Mean_TotalDue = mean(TotalDue,na.rm = TRUE),
              **for (i in 1:18)** {
                     **wm(i)** = weighted.mean(**Month(i)**,TotalDue,na.rm=TRUE),
               }
)
```

if I try a function and within the function concatenating "wm" and "Month" with *i* I get a string in return not an object...
I need to be able somehow to print a line of script that will be properly read by the system.

I am making a transition from SAS - there the analyst can print within a macro whatever script lines he/she wants and they will be included in the execution.

Pls Find below an example of my dataset:

```
structure(list(TotalDue = c(581.2, 1187.61, 763.04, 44.73, 250.5
), Vintage = c(201306, 201306, 201306, 201306, 201306), EasyClientMerge = c(400036L, 
400037L, 400040L, 400045L, 400047L), Month1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0
), Month2 = c(25.81, 15.16, 65.53, 100, 100), Month3 = c(53.34, 
15.16, 100, 100, 100), Month4 = c(87.75, 15.16, 100, 100, 100
), Month5 = c(100, 15.16, 100, 100, 100), Month6 = c(100, 15.16, 
100, 100, 100), Month7 = c(100, 15.16, 100, 100, 100), Month8 = c(100, 
15.16, 100, 100, 100), Month9 = c(100, 15.16, 100, 100, 100), 
    Month10 = c(100, 15.16, 100, 100, 100), Month11 = c(100, 
    15.16, 100, 100, 100), Month12 = c(100, 15.16, 100, 100, 
    100), Month13 = c(100, 15.16, 100, 100, 100), Month14 = c(100, 
    15.16, 100, 100, 100), Month15 = c(100, 15.16, 100, 100, 
    100), Month16 = c(100, 15.16, 100, 100, 100), Month17 = c(100, 
    15.16, 100, 100, 100), Month18 = c(100, 15.16, 100, 100, 
    100)), .Names = c("TotalDue", "Vintage", "EasyClientMerge", 
"Month1", "Month2", "Month3", "Month4", "Month5", "Month6", "Month7", 
"Month8", "Month9", "Month10", "Month11", "Month12", "Month13", 
"Month14", "Month15", "Month16", "Month17", "Month18"), row.names = c(2L, 
3L, 4L, 8L, 9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Any suggestions?

BR

Comment: Please make your example reproducible, in that way we can much more effectively help you. In short, the answer is to organise the data in your `data.frame` differently so `ddply` can effectively deal with it.

Comment: Apologize for the delay - I have edited my original question and added-up an example of my data frame.

Answer (score 0):

Total guess, without a reproducible example, but I think tapply will solve your problem.

This will loop over a data frame broken down by a set of factors. [I've written an entry level tutorial on my blog](http://scottishsnow.wordpress.com/2013/10/11/tapply/).

Comment: Hi Mike - thanks for the answer. Now I've posted an example... Trhe issues I have are 2: I am not doing the same operation on  the whole data set (for sum of the variables I do mean, for other counts, for other weighted.mean. The other is that the number of Month variable will differ every month so I want to make it flexible (for example do weighted.mean on i = 1:(length(dataframe)-3))4